# Running a loop in parallel using multiple cores in R

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have an iterative loop that I want to execute several times so that I can compare the chains. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with parallel processing in the R language and I am not sure which package is appropriate for this problem.

Since my workstation has 4 processors, and R only ever uses a single core, it seems to me that I should be able to execute this loop simultaneously on each core. In other words, how can I tell R to "run this loop once on each available core"?

Comment: In R it may be more efficient to avoid the loop and use a vectorized function instead (which is possible in many but not all situations, so it depends on what you are trying to do with your loop)

Comment: Maybe this document will help you http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/doMC.pdf
and http://www.matthewckeller.com/html/parallelization.html

Comment: See [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) package.

Comment: @beginneR the problem is that it is an iterative loop–the next values depend on the previous, so I do not see how I can vectorize it.

Comment: @rischan Thanks for the document. Looks promising.